# Password Encoder in Spring boot Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, password-encryption

I want to make an authentication with password encoding.
When I use `PasswordEncoder()` and `setPasswordEncryptor()`, it gives me errors:

> PasswordEncoder() : Cannot instantiate the type PasswordEncoder and for setPasswordEncryptor() : The method setPasswordEncryptor(StrongPasswordEncryptor) is undefined for the type PasswordEncoder.

I don't know what I should I do and I search for it too much.
thank you guys!

```java
import org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("daoAuthenticationProvider")
    public void setAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor) {
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new PasswordEncoder();
        passwordEncoder.setPasswordEncryptor(passwordEncryptor);
        return passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                                               UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthManager(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/products", "/product/show/*", "/console/*", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();

        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        httpSecurity.headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code snippet. It should work.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
    return authProvider;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this : Spring Boot 2

```
@Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
@Qualifier("passwordEncoder")
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}
```